# LINQ on Directory.GetFiles with Substring in Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, substring

I have a directory that has two *.xml files that starts with "L". I tried various LINQ syntax but all returns no files. It should be simple enough but I can't wrap my head about this problem.

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
    .Where(p => p.Substring(0,1) == "L");

IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml")
    .Where(p => (p.Substring(0,1) == "L"))

IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
    .Where(p => p.StartsWith("L"))
```

Comment: Just use a debugger next time. Then you will see that those files have absolute paths and not relative to that directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`EnumerateFiles` or `GetFiles` return the full-path, not only the file-name.

You can use the `IO.Path` class and `GetFileName` or `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`:

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
    .Where(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p).StartsWith("L"));
```

If you want to ignore the case, so accept also `l`, use the overload of [`StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
    .Where(p => Path.GetFileName(p).StartsWith("L", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

---

As commented, in this case the easiest way is to use the `searchPattern` of [`EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "L*.xml");
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at these two:

```
IEnumerable<string> files = 
        Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml")
        .Where(p => (p.Substring(0,1) == "L"));
IEnumerable<string> files = 
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
        .Where(p => p.StartsWith("L"));
```

You have to understand that the path will be with "c:\blah\blah\blah\L001.xml".

You need to get the filename first. This can be achieved by using `Path.GetFilename(...)`:

```
IEnumerable<string> files = 
        Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml")
        .Where(p => (Path.GetFilename(p).Substring(0,1) == "L"));
IEnumerable<string> files = 
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
        .Where(p => Path.GetFilename(p).StartsWith("L"));
```

---

**Edit** Clemens' suggestion in the comment is probably the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

This should be the quickest way instead of getting all files and filtering afterwards

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "L*.xml")
```